# Cannot add attachments through Attributes window of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, attachments, html-popup

I am trying to add *.png files to shapefiles in ArcMap like this:

1. Enable attachments through ArcToolbox
2. Open the Editor Toolbar and select "start editing"
3. In Attributes window, click the paperclip icon next to "Attachments" and add the .png file
4. You can view the image with HTML popup

I have been adding attachments like that until now. I cannot get the paperclip icon to show up in the Attributes window and I get an error message when enabling the attachments that reads "Attachments already enabled for this database". I have tried disabling attachments and re-enabling them, but I get the same error message and there is still no paperclip icon.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things to check when you cannot see the Attachments (paper clip) icon in the Attributes window are:

1. That you are using a Standard or Advanced level license - you cannot add/edit/delete attachments with a Basic license
2. That you have started editing
3. That you have the attributes of the correct layer active within your Attributes window